# Finding minimum with geometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

We have variables $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},...,x_{n}>0$ and constants $c_{1},c_{2},c_{3},...,c_{n}>0$ where $n=2k, k\in\mathbb{N}$

Find the minimum of $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x^2_{1}+\left(x_{2}-c_{1}\right)^{2}}$
Express your answer with constants $c_{1},c_{2},c_{3},...,c_{n}$

Comment: Geometry, really ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Triangle inequality applies, so arguably one can construct a geometric proof that the length of a path composed of line segments is never lower than the direct segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i=X$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nc_i=C$.

Thus, by Minkowski (triangle inequality) and C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{x_i^2+(x_{i+1}^2-c_i)^2}\geq\sqrt{X^2+(X-C)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{(1+1)(X^2+(C-X)^2)}\geq \frac{X+C-X}{\sqrt2}=\frac{C}{\sqrt2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

[My idea:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ljOO.png)

Therefore the length of hypotenuse is
$$\sqrt{(c_{1}+c_{3}+c_{5}+...+c_{n-1})^2+(c_{2}+c_{4}+c_{6}+...+c_{n})^2} \ge \dfrac{c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3}+...+c_{n-1}+c_{n}}{\sqrt{2}}$$